# ECLIPSE : SVN icon decorations

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

Is there a way to change icons under eclipse ?

example :
[image]

I'd like to change the dirty flag under SVN when a class has been changed

Comment: I think this question is out of the scope of SO, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: If there is no setting for it in the SVN preferences you won't be able to change it.

Comment: @baudsp Questions about development tools are on topic.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you. GeekJunior please excuse my misguided comment.

Comment: It is probably just an image in the plugin jar. You can try to find appropriate jar in plugins folder and swap that icon.

Comment: you can change the font or the color in the SVN preferences but didn't find the icons, even in the plugins folder.
Anyway thank you for your quick answers

Comment: In plugins folder inside **jar** of specific plugin.