# What do the asterisk and plus symbols mean in Eclipse's Package Explorer tree?

Tags: java, eclipse

I don't know why the asterisk is shown in some packages I highlighted. And why is the + sign shown in the `src` package and `src/test/resources`?

[image: Eclipse's Package Explorer tree]

Comment: And what about + sign??? also the java editor is inactive in these particular files

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915686/eclipse-svn-icon-decorations

Answer (score 5):

These symbols are aspects of version control: The star indicates there are changes in that directory (or any subdirectory of it) which have not yet been comitted to version control. The + means that this is a new file, not in version control yet.